# RewriteBase explanation please

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a test site at http://domain.com/narborough on Xammp (where domain.com is actually snug but stackoverflow blocks snug for some inane reason)
I've got an .htaccess in that directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
</IfModule>
```

but    http://domainname.com/narborough/example
returns a 404 rather than 
going to 
http://domainname.com/narborough/index.php?p=example

I have extensively googled and tried different RewriteBase like /narborough/ snug/narborough/

What's the simple principle please?

Comment: What is `snug/` here? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: snug is the name of the computer XAMPP is on which on my network

Comment: .htaccess is in the narborough directory. I have so many sites in the snug directory on my home server (an old xp machine that just acts like a development server)

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` set to?

Comment: phpinfo says C:/xampp/htdocs - the server is on a different machine to the one I'm accessing it on

Comment: So `narborough` is directory like `C:/xampp/htdocs/narborough`

Comment: That is correct. For now I've done it in the root directory. But it would be useful to set them up in various subdirectorys, which are devlopment equivalents to separate domains!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `/narborough/.htaccess` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /narborough/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```